# How can I create a search form that searches files in a folder?

Tags: php, html, search-engine

I have a search feature on my website. I would like it to search through a certain folder for files on my server and display results from there. I'd rather not use databases.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: question is too vague, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: several seconds later ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$dir = "/your_folder_here/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file == $_POST['SEARCHBOX_INPUT']){
                echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

From php.net mostly. Obviously change your file path. Also change the $_POST command in the middle to whatever the name of your search box input is. This will only find exact matches of your search. Some changes could be made to find close matches.

Comment: I normally would condemn this for pretty much copying another answer, but you explained it and modified it according to the OP's needs. +1. However, a line-by-line explanation might be helpful here.

Comment: Yeah, I posted mine a few seconds after the previous answer-er. granted, we both did the logical thing and hit up good ole' php.net

Comment: okay, so just to be sure, i just put this at the top of my code, and replace "your_folder_here" with my folder and "$_POST" with the name of my search box input. correct?

Comment: Well, change SEARCHBOX_INPUT to the name of your input. This assumes that you are just using a standard submit button and form with post on your search box, no ajax. This script will echo out a link to the file that matches the search input. Let me know if it gives you any trouble. Good luck.

Comment: I would simply put this code on the desired results page. There's really no reason not to. Just place this entire section of code within the html where you would want the results to appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "/etc/php5/";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file == 'songs1.php')
                //ur code here ... 
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

I got this from [PHP.net](http://php.net). I hope this helps you.

Comment: and i have multiple files to search for not just one

Comment: It *would* be helpful to link to the actual page on PHP.net. Unless you'd like to explain this here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, although it displays all the files which are in that directory and it does not give a brief description of each file. I dont know if you can help modify it.

```
<?php
print "<h2>Showing results for $search</h2>";

$dirName="MYBOOKS";
$dp=opendir($dirName);
chdir($dirName);

 while ($currentFile !== false) {

$currentFile = readDir($dp);
$theFiles[] = $currentFile;
}

$BookFiles= preg_grep("/pdf$|gif$|png$|jpg$|jed$/", $theFiles);

$output="";
foreach ($BookFiles as $currentFile) {

$output .= <<< Here
<ul>
<li><a href=MYBOOKS/$currentFile>$currentFile</a></li>
</ul>
Here;
}

 $fp=fopen("BookIndex.htm","w");
fputs ($fp,$output);
fclose($fp);

readfile ("BookIndex.htm");
```

?>