# search folder on server and display results

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I search a folder on my server and display the results on my webpage?  I found a similar question at [How can I create a search form that searches files in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613962/how-can-i-create-a-search-form-that-searches-files-in-a-folder) but I can't figure out how to connect the php script to my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
<input id="query" type="text"/><button id="search-button"  onclick="?????">Search</button>
</div>

<script>
var q=document.getElementById("query");



</script>


<?php
$dir = "/uploads/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if($file == $_POST['q']){
            echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example you saw is just that; an example. Using `$dir = "/uploads/";` should either be a full system path `$dir = "/var/user/you/httpdocs/uploads/";` or a relative one `$dir = "uploads/";` or `$dir = "../uploads/";`

Comment: What do you, exactly, want? Do you want search files names? or contents inside those files?

Comment: Basically, I'd like to do a keyword search of a folder on my server.  I'd type in a term in a search box on my web page, press search, and then get the results, i.e. the names of matching files on my web page.  Then, I'd like to be able to open those files, perhaps through a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can post info to a php script seamlessly (asynchronously) with jQuery's post method. Then you can return the data to the calling page and display it.

So have the php script that lists/finds the files and the html page separate.  Then in the html page use javascript and jQuery to post to that php finder script. Something like:

```
$.post('phpFileFinder.php', {fileName: fileNameJSvar}, function(data){

        $("#divId").html(data);
 });
```

Then in your php script you can have:

```
$dir = $_POST['fileName'];
$fileArray = array();
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file == $_POST['q']){
        array_push($fileArray,'<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
    }
}
closedir($dh);
}

print_r($fileArray);
}
```

Comment: Could you check my post and see where I'm going wrong?  I tried to follow your suggestions, but I can't seem to get it to show results.

Comment: check my edit.  It should be `array_push(..` not `push`

Comment: I think something else is wrong with my code because after i changed to array_push, I still didn't get any results.

Comment: you'll have to set the path of the file/dir relative to where the php script is executing.